# How can I run Automator Quick Actions in Firefox?

Tags: macos, automator, firefox

I have an Automator Quick Action that works fine in Mail, BBEdit, Pages, and a number of other applications that allow you to select text.

This Quick Action takes selected text, searches a MySQL database for that word or phrase, pops up a list of records it found, allows the user to select one, then puts the content of that search in the clipboard.

However, it does not appear on the contextual menu in Firefox. I changed the "Workflow receives content" from "text" to "rich text" and re-started Firefox, but it still doesn't show up on the menu.

Is there some way from within Automator to put a contextual menu item on the Firefox contextual menu for selected text?

Comment: Does it show up under File > Services? Can you get ANY Quick Action/Service to show in Firefox? Not all cross-platform apps support all Mac-specific features. Also, version numbers of your OS and of Firefox would be useful.

Comment: Doh! I should have thought of that! Write it up an an answer, and I'll mark it answered. Thanks! It was on the application menu: Firefox —> Services —> A Quote With

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all cross-platform apps may handle Mac-specific features in expected ways, such as having (or not having) Quick Actions in Contextual Menus.

However, Quick Actions/Services should appear in the **File > Services** sub-menu.

Comment: NEWS FLASH: After accessing my Quick Action *one time* from the Services sub-menu, it began appearing on the contextual menu! Looks like Firefox may have a cacheing issue somewhere.